# Can a covariance matrix be recalculated for dummy variables?

Tags: binary-data, covariance-matrix, categorical-encoding

Say I have the following sample from a continuous variable $X$ and a categorical (dichotomous) variable $Y$:

```
  X Y
0.5 1
2.3 2
2.2 2
1.8 1
```

Moreover, the covariance matrix between $X$ and $Y$ is also known:

$$
\Sigma_{XY} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sigma_{XX} & \sigma_{XY} \\
    \sigma_{YX} & \sigma_{YY}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0.5 & 1.2 \\
    1.2 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now let's say we have dummy-coded $Y$, so our data looks like this:

```
  X Y1 Y2
0.5  1  0
2.3  0  1
2.2  0  1
1.8  1  0
```

My question is: how can we calculate the covariance matrix between $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?

$$
\Sigma_{XY_1Y_2} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sigma_{XX} & \sigma_{XY_1} & \sigma_{XY_2} \\
    \sigma_{Y_1X} & \sigma_{Y_1Y_1} & \sigma_{Y_1Y_2} \\
    \sigma_{Y_2X} & \sigma_{Y_2Y_1} & \sigma_{Y_2Y_2}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0.5 & ? & ? \\
    ? & ? & ? \\
    ? & ? & ?
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In my actual problem, I can often bootstrap my way into getting a fair estimate for this matrix, but it is very important for me to find the analytical solution as well. For what it's worth, *the proportion of each category in the population is also known*.

Answer (score 1):

We've got:

$$Y_1 = 1 - Y_2 \;\;(1)$$
$$Y = Y_2 + 1 \;\;(2)$$
$$Y = 2 - Y_1 \;\;(3)$$

So, using equation $(1)$:
$$\sigma_{Y_1Y_1} = Var(Y_1) = 0 + (-1)^2 Var(Y_2) = \sigma_{Y_2Y_2}$$
$$\sigma_{Y_1Y_2} = \sigma_{Y_2Y_1} = Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = -Cov(Y_1, Y_1) = -\sigma_{Y_1Y_1}$$

... and using equations (2, 3):

$$Var(Y) = 0.4 = Var(Y_2) = Var(Y_1)$$

As for the other two $\sigma$s, assuming that the covariance $\sigma_{XY}$ was calculated using their numerical values :

$$\sigma_{XY} = Cov(X, Y) = E((X - E(X))(Y - E(Y))) = 1.2$$
$$= E((X-E(X))(Y_2 + 1 - 1 - E(Y_2))) = \sigma_{XY_2}$$

Similarly:

$$\sigma_{XY} = E((X-E(X))(2 - Y_1 - 2 + E(Y_1))) = -\sigma_{XY_1}$$

So the final answer is:

$$\Sigma_{XY} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0.5 & -1.2 & 1.2 \\
    -1.2 & 0.4 & -0.4 \\
    1.2 & -0.4 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}$$

... and that should finish the answer if I've not made any errors!

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll try to reproduce it in my example (and hopefully properly expand to the polytomous case). As for your last remark, correlations involving a continuous and a dichotomous variable are commonly calculated using point-biserial correlation. I am assuming a properly-calculated $\Sigma_{XY}$ could be derived from that, but that's something I'll check later.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Btw, I've made an edit, removing my unreasonable and unneeded $Bernoulli$ assumption.